Tv series abut kids/adults who had cars that could turn into big robot animals
Does anyone remember a tv series in which there where small cars that could turn into big animal robots to fight. I remember that they where in a different world when firing. There was also a girl with bluish-green hair. And one of the main characters had a blue car, the blue hair girl had a horse/unicorn one I think. Three was also a purple-black bus car. Does anyone know the name of this!?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What's a "bus car?"  Are you talking about a minivan or a minibus?

Hey it was a minibus if I remember correctly

I've never seen it myself, but this seems to be Screechers Wild!. You can watch it on Tubi or Pluto TV. The girl with the bluish-green hair is Ann. She gets a pegasus called KnightVision. The blue car is probably Jayhawk.

Oh my god yes, thank you so much

@Darta You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as accepted, which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
